# Can the given transformation possible for given determinant?

Tags: self-learning, determinant

[image]

In forth step $(x-1)(x-2)$ is obtained by applying transformation R<sub>$1 \frac{1}{(x+1)}$</sub>  and R<sub>$2 \frac{1}{(x+2)}$</sub>.

But we get value of $x = -1$ or $ x = -2$ so $\frac{1}{(x+1)}$ and $\frac{1}{(x+2)}$  will be undefined because value of x can be -1 and -2.

So my question is can we apply R<sub>1i</sub> and R<sub>2i</sub>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Step four, $(x+1) , (x+2)$ is obtained not by applying transformation $R_{1\frac{1}{x+1}}$ and $R_{2\frac{1}{x+2}}$. Since determinant function is linear in each row, we have 
\begin{align}det
\begin{bmatrix}
c.a_{1,1} & c.a_{1,2} & c.a_{1,3}\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3}\\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3}
\end{bmatrix} = c .det
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3}\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3}\\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Above identity is true for every row not just first row.
Hence we have the step four using the linearity of determinant in first and third row.

Comment: but it means $R_{1 \frac{1}{x+1}}$ would be undefined if x = -1 then how can we use that?

Comment: you dcn't need to apply $R_{1\frac{1}{x+1}}$. All I am saying is , if $v,w,z$ denote the first ,second and third row of the matrix, then, by linearity of the determinant in each variable (keeping fixed other two) give you $det(c.v,w,z)= c .det(v,w,z)$. There is no need to divide first row by $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $(x+1)=0$, the left hand side in the fourth step is zero. So the transformation still holds.

Comment: I meant  (1/x+1) will be (1/0) which would be undefined. Thus RHS will be undefined

Comment: Note he didn't use your notation. All that matters is that equality is preserved under the transformation for all $x$. It is true for $x \neq -1$ and $x = -1$, therefore it's valid for all $x$.